# Is there a way to check what you are running a python program in?

Tags: python, terminal, python-idle, sys

I want to create a script for just Terminal and IDLE, but I don't know how. Using `if 'idlelib' in sys.modules:` works for seeing if it is running in IDLE, but is there a way to use the same code to find if it is in Terminal by replacing `'idlelib'`?

Comment: What do you mean by "for just Terminal and IDLE"? What would be *not* Terminal or IDLE?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Solid point, but I wanted to make sure, because I plan on turning it into an executable for Terminal with arguments but still use inputs if it is in IDLE.

Comment: Are you asking how you can determine whether a Python file is run as a script, or imported as a module?

Comment: @mkrieger1 No, I want to get the name of the process running the script and then check if it is what I want it to be.

Comment: And what do you intend to do if is not what you want it to be? Or what would be the problem if you didn't do this check at all?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Return something that says to the user that they should use IDLE or Terminal. Because I don't have a windows device, I don't want people running it on Command Line in case of issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `psutil` and `os`

```
import psutil
import os
if psutil.Process(os.getpid()).parent().name() in ["cmd.exe","bash"]:
    print("in cmd")
```

Using idle it returned `'pythonw.exe'` which shows this works.

Comment: What would I change "cmd.exe" to because I'm using Terminal, not windows Command Line?

Comment: Running on Centos you would get `bash` as a result but you can also try printing using `print(psutil.Process(os.getpid()).parent().name())` to get what the terminal is in your case

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psutil'
Is it something I have to download first?

Comment: I am  running Python 3.8.5 and psutil exists.

Comment: @ncmathsadist I'm trying to download it using pip3 now, I guess it just has to be downloaded.